# radio buttons in php to select an apointment slot

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I am looking for a solution so that the user can select an appointment slot. I am trying to add a radio button, but not sure how to go about it.

```
<?php
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $dbname = "hairdressingapointments";

   // Create connection
   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
   // Check connection
   if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
   } 

   $sql = "SELECT `ApointmentDate`, `ApointmentTime` FROM `apointments` 
    WHERE  `ApointmentDate` between curdate() and curdate()+ interval '50' day 
    && quantity=1 && staffID=901";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);

   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo " Apointment Date: " . $row["ApointmentDate"]. " Appointment Time: " 
        . $row["ApointmentTime"]. "<br>";
       }
   } else {
      echo "0 results";
   }
   $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You'd want to create a form when you fetch the results and echo out `<input type="radio"...` for each of the appointment slots. If I were you, I'd do a `<select>` dropdown instead.

Comment: @Darren is right. If more appointment slots will be added, the radio buttons generated could mess up other elements of your html.